# Rended cloth looks torn

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

I am using Blender 3.2.1
I have a cloth simulation. It looks even in Layout:
[image]

But when i render image, T-shirt looks "torn":
[image]

I have made the character big

I have tried baking cloth once again one by one (shorts - T-shirt - jacket), but it did not help

my file https://cloud.mail.ru/public/THzN/ySSDGoZoG

Could you please tell me how to fix it? How to make cloth look even in render?
I am new to Blender and I will be greatful for any help

Comment: Are there any modifiers on the tshirt that are only visible in the render? Like a subsurf modifier that has 0 Viewport Subdivisions but 2 for the Render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many subdivisions before the cloth modifier. The first and the last one make sense but the one in the middle is not necessary. If you would like to have even more details, only increase the numbers of the latest Subsurf modifier.

The reason why it is working in the viewport but not in the final render is because of the different settings in your Subsurfmodifiers, like Jakemoyo mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I deleted the Subdivision modifier in the middle and it helped